# Get queryset data of django by ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to sending a json response from django views.
Using below code.

```
msg_obj=Message.objects.all()
msg_list=list(msg_obj.values())
print(msg_list)
return JsonResponse(msg_list,safe=False)
```

Then on success in ajax I am doing like this:-

```
success: function (data) {
        alert(data['id'])
                    $('#msg-list').append("<p> he" + data['id'] + "</p>");

        }
```

if I print msg_list in django it gives me result like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'username_id': 2, 'fusername_id': 3, 'text': 'hello friends'},{'id': 1, 'username_id': 2, 'fusername_id': 3, 'text': 'hello friends'}]
```

I have tried many combinations but unable to get or print the data back at client side(ajax on success function).

**EDIT:**  Every time i try to access data in ajax i got undefined alert!!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You haven't said what's going wrong. What actually happens in the success function? What does the alert show?

Comment: it only gave  me undefined in html !

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` give you?? Try `data[0].id`

Comment: Yeah it worked but how i can use loops in this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send a list of items in the Ajax response, so in the success function `data` is an array of objects. You need to loop through:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    $('#msg-list').append("<p> he" + item['id'] + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: How could the callback values be sent to **another (a different) page**, and not display on the calling page?